# How to create routes in zend with params

Tags: zend-framework

How can I create a url route in Bootstrap with param eg
www.example.com/index/careers/jobs
www.example.com/index/careers/placements

where index is my controller and careers is the action. jobs and placements are params respectively. So far below is what I have created but it would not work for me.

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex
        (
                'index/careers/jobs',
                array
                (
                        'controller' => 'index',
                        'action' => 'careers'
                ),
                array
                (
                        1=> 'jobs'
                ),
                'index/careers/jobs'
        );
        $router->addRoute('careers', $route);

Answer (score 0):

in your **Bootstrap** add this function

```
 protected function _initRouter()
 {
    $router->addRoute('yourRouteName', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('yournewLocationRoute', array('controller' => 'toYourControllerName', 'action' => 'toYourActionName')));

 }
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but I didn't try it as I already figured out how to do it;

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex 
  (
    'index/careers/([a-zA-Z\-]+)',
    array
    (
     'controller' => 'index',
     'action' => 'careers'
    ),
    array
    (
     1 => 'careerpage'
    ),
    'index/careers/%s'
  );
  $router->addRoute('careers-route', $route);

And in my action controller, the parameter is retrieved;
$request = $this->getRequest();
$careerpage = $request->getParam('careerpage');

switch($careerpage){
//blocks of code

}